# Como usar Shadows?

Tags: android

Como utilizar o efeito shadows em meus componentes?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poderia ser assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[Outras possibilidades](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

Comment: Sim mas onde eu coloco esse xml?

Comment: Na pasta res\drawable

Comment: Mais no componente eu coloco como? Background?

Comment: Sim. Adicione isso ao background do componente.